# Flutter Dependencies Error DART

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am doing an App in flutter, and i had the following issue

> /Users/pedro/Desktop/Development/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color packages get
>   Running "flutter packages get" in wemystic...
>   The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f.
>   Because flutter_cache_manager >=0.1.0-rc.1 depends on uuid >=0.0.7 <1.0.3 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, flutter_cache_manager >=0.1.0-rc.1 is forbidden.
>   So, because wemystic depends on flutter_cache_manager 0.1.0-rc.1, version solving failed.
>   pub get failed (1)
>   Process finished with exit code 1

My dependencies in pubspec.yaml are:

```html
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: any
  google_sign_in: any
  flutter_html_view: any
```

Thanks

Comment: Update Flutter then try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flutter_cache_manager` package is outdated and needs update

- https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cache_manager/issues/26
- https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cache_manager/issues/41

Adding this to `pubspec.yaml` should fix it as workaround until the package is updated

```
dependency_overrides:
  uuid: ^1.0.3
```

Comment: Working now, but the images on html don't load

Comment: I don't know if that is supposed to work because the `flutter_cache_manager seems a bit outdated or if your code is not correct. `dependency_overrides` is always on your own risk.